# Stephen Cleary's new logging pattern question about async

Tags: c#

I like Stephen Cleary's new [logging pattern](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/a-new-pattern-for-exception-logging.html) once I tested it. However, there is something that I don't understand:

> The solution here unfortunately does not work well with async code. This is because async will cause exceptions to be caught and then re-thrown at the point of the await. So, the exception filter runs at the point of the await instead of where the exception was originally thrown.

I would like to get an example of that, because it seems that my code works fine for me with `Handle(...)`/his `True(...)` and no `throw;`.

I made `SubscribeAsync` throw an exception on purpose.

```cs
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await SubscribeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (Handle(() => _logger.LogError(ex, "Unexpected error.")))
    {
    }
}

public static class ExceptionFilterUtility
{
    public static bool Handle(Action action)
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }

    public static bool Propagate(Action action)
    {
        action();
        return false;
    }
}
```

My stacktrace is:

```
[2021-03-13 20:16:32 Error] ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager
Unexpected error.
ElonMuskBot.Core.Exceptions.RequestFailedException: Error while subscribing to the Spot candlestick update stream
   at ElonMuskBot.Core.Clients.SpotBotClient.SubscribeToCandleUpdatesAsync(String symbol, KlineInterval timeInterval, Action`1 onMessage) in E:\GitHub\elonmuskbot\src\ElonMuskBot.Core\Clients\SpotBotClient.cs:line 88
   at ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager.SubscribeAsync() in E:\GitHub\elonmuskbot\src\ElonMuskBot.Core\TradeManagers\LiveTradeManager.cs:line 54
   at ElonMuskBot.Core.TradeManagers.LiveTradeManager.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in E:\GitHub\elonmuskbot\src\ElonMuskBot.Core\TradeManagers\LiveTradeManager.cs:line 38
```

Comment: And the output you're claiming "is no problem" was...

Comment: @CaiusJard, I didn't get your point.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of your exception ?

Comment: @CaiusJard, https://i.imgur.com/NXEQwVr.png, which is correct. It's exactly there.

Comment: You took an screenshot of text that could be easily copypasted into your question...

Comment: @CaiusJard, It's too long

Comment: I've never seen SO enforce a character limit, but given that you've only shown about 6 lines in your screenshot you clearly have a handle on "what is a sensible amount of data necessary to demonstrate the point" so feel free to exercise the same judgement when editing text into the question

Comment: @CaiusJard, it's too long by 180 characters. https://pastebin.com/s8yCXtEV. You can try pasting it

Comment: Worked for me, how bizarre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get an example of that, because it seems that my code works fine for me with Handle(...)/his True(...) and no throw;.

The point of that pattern is to capture logging *scopes* at the point of the `throw`. Exception handling itself works fine either way, but the captured scopes are different.

The logging scopes are captured properly for synchronous code, since the exception filters are actually executed at the point of the `throw`. So the exception is logged at the `throw`, including all logging scopes that are present.

However, it does not work properly for asynchronous code. The exceptions will be logged just fine, but the logging scopes will not be present. This is because the exception filters are executed at the point of the `await`, not the point of the `throw`.

So here's an example that will not properly capture the exception logging scopes:

```
public async Task SubscribeAsync()
{
  using var _ = _logger.BeginScope("This will not be logged");
  await Task.Yield();
  throw new InvalidOperationException("This will be logged");
}
```

Since writing that blog post, I've developed a better solution that works for both synchronous and asynchronous exceptions and [released it as a library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Logging). I haven't gotten around to writing a new blog post (sorry!) but as soon as I do I'll point the old solution to the newer one.

The newer solution is .NET Core only, since it ties into `ILogger`. Example usage:

```
// Don't forget to call IServiceCollection.AddExceptionLoggingScopes() in your startup.
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  try
  {
    await SubscribeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    using (_logger.BeginCapturedExceptionLoggingScopes(ex))
      _logger.LogError(ex, "Unexpected error.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw the alternatives: https://github.com/Tolyandre/serilog-throw-context-enricher. I'm actually using Serilog. Which one is a better idea to use?

Comment: I would definitely use the Serilog one, then. Because you can set it up in your startup and then not have to bother with `BeginCapturedExceptionLoggingScopes`. `BeginCapturedExceptionLoggingScopes` only exists because the Microsoft dependency injection library is not powerful enough to extend loggers to do this automatically. The Serilog library extends the Serilog loggers directly so it doesn't have the same limitation, so its API is easier to use (no `BeginCapturedExceptionLoggingScopes` necessary).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!